# Specflow: How to generate a unique string by ValueRetriever and store it for the current Scenario, without any issue in parallel execution

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin, scenarios

to make test data unique for correctly selecting in tests. I'm looking for solution to generate a unique string and replace it to the "(*)" in Feature file. The generated unique string should be remained to the end of the Scenario, and it's safe when tests are executed parallelly (each Scenario should hold its own unique string).

I currently generate the unique string by create a custom class `UniqueStringRetriever : IValueRetriever` but duno how to register it to avoid parallel execution problem.

Does anyone have idea for this situation please leave your help in here. I do appreciate that.

```
    Background:
        Given the following Customer
          | First Name | Last Name |
          | David (*)  | Brown     |

    Scenario: Search Customer by First Name
        When user search Customer by First Name
          | First Name |
          | David (*)  |
        Then the result list displays 'David (*)' customer
```

Comment: So you want the "First Name" to be unique?

Comment: Why do you need it unique?

Comment: Let say the system allows customers to have same name, but diff email address. So in the UI  the Customer drop-down can list some "David" menu items as well, If I just use the "David" for the first name, and the test is executed repeatedly (due to rerun after failure etc...) then we cannot control which "David" has been selected in that test run. At the moment I have the unique string generated from DateTime.Now:MMddhmmssfffff

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the step definitions and what you have tried for the UniqueStringRetriever class? We cannot answer your question without a [repro].